# can you suggest me, why i am getting error like expectated declaration specifiers or '...' before size_t

Tags: int

```
int bidi_visualize_line(const VisualString* vs, char* outputStringUtf8, size_t capacity);
```

> I am getting an error like expected declaration specifiers or '..' before size_t. where 
>   should i use ssize_t and size_t
>
> small doubt, what are .a files and how to open them using some installer in my redhat linux > pc.. I tried but it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `stddef.h` — where `size_t` is defined — is not included. Try adding:

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

Comment: If an answer solves your issue, you should generally upvote it and/or accept the best one. In this case, there's not much competition :)